# What’s the significance of c’(t) = 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, curves

Let c be a curve such that $R\rightarrow R^3$. Let c’(t) be the derivative of c with respect to some parameterization t.

If $c(t_o) = 0$ for some $t_o$, what is the significance? Is the existence of c'=0 independent of parametrization.

Context: Working on a numeric a numeric integration of bios-savarte law. Decided to plot abs of my tan vector to my curve and noticed it hit zero, so now I’m trying to diagnose the issue. Ie is it error in coding/plotting or am in for a big set back. I need the unit tan vector at each point for Bios-Savart.

The particular curve I am trying to describe is a toroidal coil. I found this equation, $$c(t,r,a,n) = (-r \sin(t/n) - a \cos(t) \sin(t/n),r \cos(t/n) + a \cos(t) \cos(t/n), a \sin(t))$$ by starting with a parametrized helix and good old fashion trial and error. The $a$ is the small radius. The $r$ is the big radius, and the $n$ is the number of loops.

Physically, it seems like $c'(t)$ should always be nonzero for a toroidal coil which makes me think I either don't understand $c'= 0$, or my function is wrong.

Comment: $c'(t)=0$ just means $c$ is stationary at time $t$

Comment: So, I wouldn't be able to observe it in a plot correct? Further, do you know if c'(t) should be nonzero for all t for a toroidal coil. (can add picture of my plot if desired).

Comment: Changed it up. What's the best way to report a long vectorial function here? Also, is the spacing ok, or should I try to space out the terms more.

Comment: @DavidK I can go back and look at other calculations now. I did mean the norm when I said abs. My bad.

Comment: @DavidK I think the issue may have been that while |c'(t)| appeared to intersect zero it may have merely approached it. Solve[] in mathematica appears to be telling me that. Maybe this was all a false alarm.

Comment: You can get close to zero by fiddling with the parameters $r,a,n$, but as far as I can tell, $\lvert c'(t)\rvert \geq a^2$. But $a^2$ could be small. It sounds like a graphing issue.

Comment: The format you used for the vector seems fine to me. You could also do a column vector if you like; the markup is like `\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}`. If you write `\sin` and `\cos` instead of `Sin` and `Cos` that should take care of the spacing.

Comment: @DavidK alright thank you for the help. What's the protocol on questions like this where no "answer" was given. Should I just delete it?

Comment: One way or another I believe it is desirable to get the question off the list of unanswered questions. You could post a short answer explaining how you resolved the problem and then accept your own answer. Or you could delete the question. Or you could accept your own answer and then a few days later delete the question. There might also be some guidance at math.meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the c’(t) outlined above never intersected zero. However the plot appeared to when n>>s>>a. It ended up being a non problem. Great fun to have that cleared up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).